# Elasticsearch use Char Filter in Analyzer to remove all characters after a "?"

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

In elasticsearch, I am trying to use an analyzer on a field which will use a filter to replace all characters after a ? is encountered into a whitespace. To do so, I am using the following filter.

```
"filter_name":{
  "type": "pattern_replace",
  "pattern": "\\?(.*)",
  "replacement": ""
}
```

But this is not working as expected. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern: `"(?<=\\?)(.*)"` and replacement: `""`

Comment: Edited my answer, Try now ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below. I've created a sample mapping and a sample `_analyze` query to see how tokens are created.

### Mapping

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(?=.*)\\?(.*)",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Query

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "Do you know? Life is crazy"
}
```

### Analysis Result

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Do",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "you",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "know",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 26,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!